# Connecting to Azure Storage Emulator in a Docker container from another container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, nginx-reverse-proxy, azure-storage-emulator

I'm currently using the microsoft/azure-storage-emulator image from DockerHub (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-storage-emulator/) to run Azure Storage Emulator in a Docker container.

However, what I'd like to do is to connect to the emulator from a separate Docker container.

It looks like the image uses an nginx reverse proxy (I have no idea why Microsoft did this) to forward the requests to the emulator.

Updating the emulator config file to the IP address of the running container is fairly straight foward:

```
<StorageEmulatorConfig>
    <services>
        <service name="Blob" url="http://172.20.0.220:20000/"/>
        <service name="Queue" url="http://172.20.0.220:20001/"/>
        <service name="Table" url="http://172.20.0.220:20002/"/>
    </services>
```

...

BUT, I am trying to figure out what I need to change for the nginx config file in order to get access to the emulator in the container.

I think `server_name` needs to be updated to the name of the running container and the `proxy_pass` needs to be updated with the IP of the container?

```
http {
proxy_http_version 1.1;
access_log off; # find way to redirect log to stdout on winodws

server {
    listen       10000;
    server_name  storage;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.0.220:20000;
    }
}

server {
    listen       10001;
    server_name  storage;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.0.220:20001;
    }
}

server {
    listen       10002;
    server_name  storage;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.20.0.220:20002;
    }
}
```

I'm exposing ports 10000, 10001 and 10002 via my Dockerfile when I go to build my own image from the Microsoft base image so the container can receive requetss on that those ports:

```
FROM microsoft/azure-storage-emulator
EXPOSE 10000 10001 10002
```

I'm using the connection string recommended on the DockerHub's image page:

DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://{ip}:{blobport}/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://{ip}:{tableport}/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://{ip}:{queueport}/devstoreaccount1;

But I keep receiving this error message when trying to connect to the emulator container from another container:

`` Failed to execute installers: 
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (504) Gateway Timeout.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.Create(TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExists(TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext)
   at NServiceBus.AzureStorageQueues.AzureStorageQueueInfrastructure..ctor(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString)
   at NServiceBus.AzureStorageQueueTransport.Initialize(SettingsHolder settings, String connectionString)
   at NServiceBus.InitializableEndpoint.<Initialize>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.InstallWindowsHost.Install(String username)
   at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Installers.WindowsInstaller.RunInstall()
Request Information
RequestID:
RequestDate:Wed, 14 Mar 2018 02:19:41 GMT
StatusMessage:Gateway Time-out ``

So, I'm not too sure what nginx config file changes I need to make in order for the one container to access the emulator in the other container or if what I want to do is even possible.

Thanks,
Mik